# check if post is set to "password protected"

Tags: password, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I'm trying to find a way to show different content if a post is set to "password protected", once the user entered the correct password.

I want to show the price of an art piece only on posts that are set to password protected.

I can't find any php code to achieve this, since all I can find includes cookies management.

something like :

```
<?php if($post is set to password protected): ?>

show price

<?php endif; ?>
```

is there a way to do this ? there must some data stored into the database somewhere right ?

any help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's two main ways:

1. You can use the [`post_password_required()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_password_required/) function. This function returns `true` if the post has a password and `false` if the post doesn't have a password, but it also returns `false` if the post had a password but the user has entered it and unlocked the post.
2. You can get the post object with `$post = get_post()` and then check `empty( $post->post_password )`. This will tell you whether a post has a password regardless of whether or not the password has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

For those prefer use SQL...

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_password` != ''
```

Note: mind to check about empty chars (like a empty space) in post_password field, it might confuse you.